# filter multiple items javascript. The values of the key pair in the objects are arrays

Tags: javascript, filter

I am trying to filter an array for an ecommerce site so that the correct items are shown.

My attempt is below. You can see that it returns 2 items but only this object should be returned as it is the only one that satisfies the conditions. Can anyone put me in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated. Any extra information required please let me know.

I have read around and at a glance it may seem that it has already been answered, but I believe the difference here is that the items are grouped together in arrays.

```js
const filter = {
  colors: ["white"],
  sizes: [9, 12],
  brands: ["adidas"]
};

const shoes = [{
    brand: "nike",
    size: 9,
    color: "white"
  },
  {
    brand: "adidas",
    size: 12,
    color: "white"
  },
  {
    brand: "nike",
    size: 7,
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    brand: "nike",
    size: 6,
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    brand: "nike",
    size: 9,
    color: "green"
  }
];

const res = shoes.filter((shoe) => {
  if (
    filter["brands"].includes(shoe.brand) &&
    filter["colors"].includes(shoe.color) &&
    filter["sizes"].includes(shoe.size)
  ) {
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

This returns the correct result. However, if you remove update filters to be the following, with brands as an empty array the result is empty, however, if the array is empty it should be disregarded.

```
const filter = {
   colors: ["white"],
   sizes: [9, 12],
   brands: []
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks all keys and not the associated key with the wanted value and takes an **some** approach (with logical OR) instead of an **every** approach (like logical AND).

---

You could get the entries from filter object and filter this array by the length of the given values.

Then filter with key and value. This requres same named keys for value and wanted values of filter object.

```js
const
    filter = { color: ["white"], size: [9, 12], brand: ["adidas"] },
    shoes = [{ brand: "nike", size: 9, color: "white" }, { brand: "adidas", size: 12, color: "white" }, { brand: "nike", size: 7, color: "red" }, { brand: "nike", size: 6, color: "green" }, { brand: "nike", size: 9, color: "green" }],
    filters = Object.entries(filter).filter(([, { length }]) => length),
    result = shoes.filter(shoe => filters.every(([k, v]) => v.includes(shoe[k])));
    
console.log(result);
```

For disparat key names, you could apply a conversion object.

```js
const
    filter = { colors: ["white"], sizes: [9, 12], brands: ["adidas"] },
    shoes = [{ brand: "nike", size: 9, color: "white" }, { brand: "adidas", size: 12, color: "white" }, { brand: "nike", size: 7, color: "red" }, { brand: "nike", size: 6, color: "green" }, { brand: "nike", size: 9, color: "green" }],
    properties = { colors: 'color', sizes: 'size', brands: 'brand' },
    filters = Object
        .entries(filter)
        .filter(([, { length }]) => length)
        .map(([k, v]) => [properties[k], v]),
    result = shoes.filter(shoe => filters.every(([k, v]) => v.includes(shoe[k])));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: hey thanks for this great answer. I posted a more simplified version for this question, but in reality the named keys for value and wanted values of filter object are different unfortunately.

Comment: then you need a conversion object which gets the key of the filter and returns the key of the object, like using the original keys of `filter`: `{ colors: 'color', sizes: 'size', brands: 'brand' }`.

Comment: yeah i have done something that and it's close, but still a bit buggy

Comment: brilliant, got it, thanks. You're a machine!

Comment: would you be able to take a look at this question and see if you can point me in the right direction - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821438/filter-objects-based-on-values-and-arrays-as-values-js